# Running Hahoop hive would pop up "Unknown protocol" error

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive

I use CDH5 version 5.12.0 installed Hadoop. Using embedded database PostgreSQL as its configed db. All the services are start. But, when input command "hive". It pop the error message as below

[root@hadoop-master ~]# /usr/bin/hive 
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-
5.12.0-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.29/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcNoSuchProtocolException): Unknown protocol: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.getProtocolImpl(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:596)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2217)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2213)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2211)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:571)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:689)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:628)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcNoSuchProtocolException): Unknown protocol: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.getProtocolImpl(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2213)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2211)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at 

org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:658)
    at `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:606)`
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:547)
    ... 8 more
```

Anyone who could give some suggestions?

Comment: kindly share your core-site.xml file?